# How to make a custom listView checkable?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview, checkbox

My problem is that if I press one of my list items, the checkbox is just checked during the time my finger touch it. I've been searching like crazy, but I have a hard time to believe that there is no simple fix to this.

Here is a sample of my code.

I am using the following XML for my list items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/text1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
android:gravity="center_vertical"

android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
android:paddingLeft="6dip"
android:paddingRight="6dip"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:textSize="25dp"
/>
```

Attached to this class, it is being used in my array adapter.

```
public class Misshandel extends Activity {

    Button misstankt;
    ListView mListView;
    ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.forhor);

        misstankt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.misstanktKnapp);
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.forhorsLista);





         final String[] misshandelMT = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.misshandelMT);

        misstankt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Misshandel.this, R.layout.custom_list_item, misshandelMT);
                mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });
}
}
```

So to sum it up, what I want to achive is to be able to check my boxes!

Here is the full class if you want to check it out: http://codepaste.net/fg3xiz

Thanks for your time!

Comment: It looks like each time you are clicking the button you are creating a new arrayadapter and setting it as the listview. So once your finger goes off the checkbox the listview has a brand new adapter and loads that into the listview. try moving the three lines in "on click" to right under where you instantiate final String[] misshandelMT

Comment: That gives the same result. :/
There is a reason why I create new adapters, you can see in my whole code here: http://codepaste.net/fg3xiz
It is because I switch between four diffrent string-arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should post more detailed information, but I'll give you my code for dialog in which you can choose several options:

`multiselect.xml'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/values"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice" >
    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/selectAll"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/select_all" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ok"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/ok" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/deselectAll"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/select_none" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the Dialog class (with support for translation bonus):

```
public class MultiSelectDialog extends Dialog {
    private final String title;
    private ListView items;
    private List<String> selectedItems;
    private HashMap<String, String> translation;
    private List<String> displayedValues;

    public MultiSelectDialog(Context context, String title, List<String> values,
            HashMap<String, String> translation) {
        super(context);
        this.title = title;
        this.translation = translation;
        if(translation != null) {
            displayedValues = FUtils.collect(translation.entrySet().iterator(),
                    new Converter<HashMap.Entry<String, String>, String>() {
                        public String convert(Entry<String, String> object) {
                            return object.getValue();
                        }
                    });
        }
        else {
            displayedValues = values;
        }
        selectedItems = new LinkedList<String>();
    }

    public List<String> getSelectedItems() {
        return selectedItems;
    }

    public void setSelectedItems(List<String> selectedItems) {
        this.selectedItems.clear();
        this.selectedItems.addAll(selectedItems);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.multiselect);

        setTitle(title);
        items = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.values);

        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, displayedValues);
        items.setAdapter(adapter);
        for(int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); ++i) {
            items.setItemChecked(i, false);
        }

        if(selectedItems != null) {
            for(int i = 0; i < selectedItems.size(); ++i) {
                String value = getTranslatedValue(selectedItems.get(i));
                for(int j = 0; j < items.getAdapter().getCount(); ++j) {
                    if(items.getAdapter().getItem(j).equals(value)) {
                        items.setItemChecked(j, true);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Button selectAll = (Button) findViewById(R.id.selectAll);
        selectAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                for(int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); ++i) {
                    items.setItemChecked(i, true);
                }
            }
        });
        Button deselectAll = (Button) findViewById(R.id.deselectAll);
        deselectAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                for(int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); ++i) {
                    items.setItemChecked(i, false);
                }
            }
        });
        Button okButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ok);
        okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                selectedItems.clear();
                for(int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); ++i) {
                    if(items.isItemChecked(i)) {
                        String item = (String) items.getItemAtPosition(i);
                        reverseTranslateAndAdd(item);
                    }
                }
                dismiss();
            }
        });
    }

    private String getTranslatedValue(String key) {
        if(translation == null) {
            return key;
        }
        return translation.get(key);
    }

    private void reverseTranslateAndAdd(String item) {
        if(translation != null) {
            for(Entry<String, String> e : translation.entrySet()) {
                String value = e.getValue();
                if(value.equals(item)) {
                    selectedItems.add(e.getKey());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            selectedItems.add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i've edited and added the whole class, so you can check  it out, but I just think that will confuse you more. 

The code you attached was pretty massive, im not sure where to find the answer in it. 

I guess what I really need is something to keep track of the index i've selected, and then set the selected item to "true", if it's pressed&released. 

Sadly I dont have time to redo the whole class, since this "fix" will have to be implemented on several classes (32 to be exact), and my presentation is tommorow.

Comment: Can you post also your layout file?

Comment: You didn't set `android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"` on your `ListView` - it may be the case.

Comment: That is amazing mate, really really amazing. I couldn't thank you enough!